# Stop further link navigating inside web browser control [WPF]

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

Hello is there something similar to AllowNavigation like in WinForms?

My search didn't yield any satisfying result.
Basically I'm trying to open a webpage inside new wpf window and stop user from clicking random links on that webpage and navigating further.

Saw something with

```
void browser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Rest of the code is :

```
public Popup_webpage(string ime)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        browser1.LoadCompleted += browser1_LoadCompleted;
        browser1.Navigating += browser1_Navigating;


        string uri = "www.google.com"
        browser1.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    void browser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        browser1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

But it just makes my webpage not display ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Once you have loaded your page, then you assign the browser_Navigating event handler.

```
public Popup_webpage(string ime)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    browser1.LoadCompleted += browser1_LoadCompleted;
    string uri = "www.google.com"
    browser1.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));

    browser1.Navigating += browser1_Navigating;
}

void browser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    browser1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

void browser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if something has changed in the browser component but I couldn't find a 'LoadCompleted' event. I used 'DocumentCompleted instead which appears to do the same thing.

Comment: Most likely.. the answer is 7 years old...